# Finding the cosine similarity of a sentence with many others in r

Tags: r, cosine-similarity

I would like to use R to find the cosine similarity of one sentence with many others. For example:

```
s1 <- "The book is on the table"  
s2 <- "The pen is on the table"  
s3 <- "Put the pen on the book"  
s4 <- "Take the book and pen"  

sn <- "Take the book and pen from the table"
```

I want to find the cosine similarity of `s1`, `s2`, `s3` and `s4` with `sn`. I understand that I have to use vectors (convert the sentences into vectors and use TF-IDF and/or dot product) but since I'm relatively new to R, I'm having a problem implementing it.

Would appreciate all help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cosine dissimilarity used by `stringdist` isn't based on words, or terms, but qgrams, which are sequences of q characters, which might or might not form words. We can intuitively see that there's something wrong with the output given in Rui's answer. The only difference between the two first sentences is *pen* and *book*, while the last sentence contains both of these words once, so we'd expect the `s1`–`sn` and `s2`–`sn` dissimilarities to be identical, which they aren't.
There are probably other R libraries that can compute more conventional cosine similarities, but it's also not too hard to do it ourselves, from first principle. And it might end up more educational.

```
sv <- c(s1=s1, s2=s2, s3=s3, s4=s4, sn=sn)

# Split sentences into words
svs <- strsplit(tolower(sv), "\\s+")

# Calculate term frequency tables (tf)
termf <- table(stack(svs))

# Calculate inverse document frequencies (idf)
idf <- log(1/rowMeans(termf != 0))

# Multiply to get tf-idf
tfidf <- termf*idf

# Calculate dot products between the last tf-idf and all the previous
dp <- t(tfidf[,5]) %*% tfidf[,-5]

# Divide by the product of the euclidean norms do get the cosine similarity
cosim <- dp/(sqrt(colSums(tfidf[,-5]^2))*sqrt(sum(tfidf[,5]^2)))
cosim
#           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]
# [1,] 0.1215616 0.1215616 0.02694245 0.6198245
```

Comment: This was so helpful, thanks a ton. If i want to get the common terms of each sentence (s1-s4) and sn, how will i use the reduce function? I know that we can use it Reduce(intersect, strsplit(sv," ")) for the entire set, but im having trouble matching sn with others...

Comment: Do you mean something like this `lapply(svs[-5], intersect, svs[[5]])`? You might also be interested in `crossprod(termf)`, which will give you the number of words in common between each pair of sentence.

Comment: Just another query, is there a way we can use the apply functions to get the number of words in each row after we use lapply(svs[-5], intersect, svs[[5]])? crossprod gives 'wrong annwers'. (I get 2 more words for each pair). I tried doing it with sn only (using crossprod(termf[, -5], termf[, 5])) but i still get wrong answers.

Comment: Ah, was thinking slightly wrong, `crossprod(termf > 0)` should give you that. Or you can use `lengths()` on any list to see the length of each element in it.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do what the question asks for is to use package `stringdist`.

```
library(stringdist)

stringdist(sn, c(s1, s2, s3, s4), method = "cosine")
#[1] 0.06479426 0.08015590 0.09776951 0.04376841
```

In the case where the strings' names have an obvious pattern, such as the ones in the question, `mget` can be of use, there will be no need to hard code the strings names one by one in the call to `stringdist`.

```
s_vec <- unlist(mget(ls(pattern = "^s\\d+")))
stringdist(sn, s_vec, method = "cosine")
#[1] 0.06479426 0.08015590 0.09776951 0.04376841
```